# Is the Lenovo Flex 5 14 inch ram upgradable?

Tags: laptop, memory, upgrade, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo Flex 5 14 inch with me, and I wanted to upgrade the RAM on it. I currently have 8gb of preinstalled RAM in the machine. However, Task Manager shows me that one slot free. I do not know whether the ram I have right now is soldered or not. Does anyone know about the RAM in this machine? I am attaching the datasheet for my laptop to this. Thanks in advance!
https://psref.lenovo.com/Detail/Lenovo%20Laptops/Lenovo_Flex_5_14?M=81C9000EUS

Comment: According to crucial you have one slot that is up-gradable to 16gb...https://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Lenovo/flex-5-%2814-inch%29

Comment: Crucial has a different model, they say it has 4gb preinstalled but i have 8 gb